# Using the 'new' modifier on a member, how can I access the 'new' member on a generic class?

Tags: c#

Given this structure:

```cs
class A {
  public List<X> MyExes;
}
class B : A {
  public new List<Y> MyExes;
}

class X {}
class Y : X {}
```

And this generic method:

```cs
void ProcessMyExes<T>(element: T) where T : A {
  element.MyExes.ForEach(x => {...});
}
```

When I call `ProcessMyExes` with an element of type `B`, it'll call `MyExes.ForEach` on `A.MyExes` rather than on `B.MyExes`. It's not a bad behavior per se, but if I want to make it so that calling `element.MyExes` will always get the most specific value no matter what, how should I write those classes? For example, I know that I can't `override` the `MyExes` attribute even though `Y` is more specific than `X`.

For the record, currently I'm dealing with this problem by casting:

```cs
void ProcessMyExes<T>(element: T) where T : A {
  if (element is B b)
    b.MyExes.ForEach(x => {...});
  else
    element.MyExes.ForEach(x => {...});
}
```

Comment: Honestly, why do you even bother with overwriting this field? What exactly you gain from it? Because to me, it sounds like a bad design to begin with. In fact this particular feature is just encouraging people to write bad code.

Comment: You can access `B.MyExes` only through a `B` reference, like you did it with casting.

Comment: You `ProcessMyExes` is invalid C#. Can you post the full and real class definitions?

Answer (score 1):

When you use this constraint:

```
where T : A
```

...you are making a bargain with the compiler. You tell it that everything you pass will be type-compatible with `A`, and in return, the compiler allows you to access any member of `A`. Since `A` has a `MyExes` property that returns a `List<X>`, it grants you access to that member. It does not grant you access to the other property that returns a `List<Y>`, since that is not a member of `A`-- if it did, you could access an object that is not type-compatible. That is no bueno.

If you want to be able to access members that return different types, you could use a scheme like this one:

```
interface IContainerFor<T>
{
    List<T> MyExes { get; }
}

class A : IContainerFor<X> 
{
    public List<X> MyExes { get; set; }
}

class B : IContainerFor<Y> 
{
    public List<Y> MyExes { get; set; }
}

void ProcessMyExes<T>(IContainerFor<T> container) 
{
    container.MyExes.ForEach( x => { 
       Assert.AreEqual(typeof(T), x.GetType())
    );  
}
```

In this case you tell the compiler that the object passed will be an `IContainerFor` with a type parameter that matches `T`.

Notice we do not need an inheritance relationship between `A` and `B` (although you could add one if you want to). Also, we do not even need the `new` keyword. It is actually quite rare that defining a `new` member is needed or appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

Technically, you could do a `dynamic` cast to get the most specific value of `MyExes`, but you can't treat the result as a `List<X>` because it could be a `List<Y>`. This seems like the wrong solution for whatever problem you're trying to solve.

For example, let's suppose the reason why you are creating a `new` property is that you want class B to have a list of `Y`s, but you can't satisfy that requirement with a property declared as `List<X>`. Declaring the property with the `new` modifier is only going to make things worse, because now you have two separate lists that are called the same thing. Let's try this instead:

```
abstract class A
{
    public abstract IReadOnlyCollection<X> MyExes { get; }
}
class B : A
{
    public readonly List<Y> MyWys = new();
    public override IReadOnlyCollection<X> MyExes => MyWys;
}

class X { }
class Y : X { }
```

Now, `ProcessMyExes` can still process the `X` values from any `A` in a type-safe way, but `B`s can have more specific types associated with them.

```
void ProcessMyExes<T>(T element) where T : A
{
    foreach (var x in element.MyExes)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

```
    var b = new B() { MyWys = { new Y()}};
    ProcessMyExes(b);
```

Also consider what degree of coupling is really necessary here. Class inheritance often gets abused, in situations where composition is more appropriate. Maybe turn `A` into an *interface* rather than a class. Or, if the only property from `A` that matters for cases like this, you can just make `ProcessMyExes` take an `IEnumerable<X>` or `IReadOnlyCollection<X>`, and expect callers to pass it the `MyExes` property rather than the whole object.